# при сборке проекта gulp определяет js файл как undefined

Tags: javascript, gulp, jade

Здравствуйте!

Когда перешел на **coffeescript** и попробовал собрать проект через **gulp**, то **js** файла в итоговой папке **dist/scripts** не было. В корне я нашел мой **js** файл названный как **undefined** без расширения, но код в нем присутствовал. До использования **coffeescript**`a все работало.

js файл, перекомпиленный из coffee, присутствует в промежуточной .tmp папке и выглядит вполне нормально

При попытке использовать тот самый js файл из .tmp папки напрямую при деплое на gh-pages на странице все равно отсутствует сам js файл, только появляется в html`e строка :

```
<script src ="replace"></script>
```

Для gulp использую yeoman generator-gulp-webapp

[рецепт, по которому собирал js из coffee](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/coffeescript.md)

основной код из gulpfile.babel.js:

```
gulp.task('html', ['views', 'styles', 'scripts', 'myjs'], () => {
const assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']});

return gulp.src(['app/*.html', '.tmp/*.html'])
  .pipe(assets)
  .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify()))
  .pipe($.if('*.css', $.minifyCss({compatibility: '*'})))
  .pipe(assets.restore())
  .pipe($.useref())
  .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml({conditionals: true, loose: true})))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'images', 'fonts', 'extras', 'myjs'], () => {
  return gulp.src('dist/**/*').pipe($.size({title: 'build', gzip: true}));
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], () => {
  gulp.start('build');
});

gulp.task('deploy', ['build'], () => {
  return gulp.src('./dist/**/*')
    .pipe($.ghPages());
});

gulp.task('scripts', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.coffee')
    .pipe($.coffee())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение своей проблемы: в основном .jade файле (**app\layouts\default.jade**), где подключаются все стили и скрипты из-за непонимания стер кусок кода, который формирует билд из набора скриптов в один. Мой пример
с ошибкой был таким:

```
// build: js
    script(src='scripts/main.js')
// endbuild
```

как оказалось после // шли не комментарии а код, когда я добавил путь (**scripts/main.js**) к будущему билду моего когда, все заработало:

```
// build:js scripts/main.js
    script(src='scripts/main.js')
// endbuild
```